# How to generate MS Test Code Coverage Report

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, mstest

I am creating an web Application using ASP.NET core and Angular 7. I have developed Unit Test cases for Web API code using MS Test Framework. In angular i was able to generate a code coverage report using Karma, But in DotNet i was not able to find out a tool to generate Coverage report.

I don't have any alternative other than using MS Test framework, so kindly don't suggest Xunit and Nunit.

It would great to have a step by step description or any resource to go through

Comment: Is this just from Visual Studio or from build script? To  use Code Coverage in Visual Studio you will need a Visual Studio Enterprise edition. [Use code coverage to determine how much code is being tested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Its from Visual Studio but i don't have Enterprise version unfortunately. I am doing my development using Professional version.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried **opencover** tool?

[opencover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover)

there might be another option called "*PartCover*" but I've never used it..